# What should the dimensions be for a banner optimized for mobile phones?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mobile

I have created a web banner for a website. Now I have to create an optimized version of the same for its mobile phone version (**when the website is viewed through a mobile browser**).

**What are the usual dimensions for this?**

I will be glad to get some help here! Thanks in advance!

Comment: very much related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53878/do-web-designers-use-the-standard-iab-web-advert-sizes-when-adding-banners

Comment: Can you show us your "banner"?  What does banner mean?  Is this an advertisement, or a piece of content?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's an exact answer to that.  I would say you want to make sure you don't fall afoul of [Google's SEO rules for mobile sites](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/common-mistakes).

Then read further into making websites ["responsive"](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/) for mobile development.  This google site gives great examples on how to pick images and CSS based on what the screen can display.  I'd say this is the industry standard.  It's not "one" image size, it's the right size for the right display.

Comment: There are banner standards, with sizes for most devices. check https://www.iab.com/

Comment: I like the original question and I don't think the downvote is merited. I stand behind what I stated.  To use IAB which is for the size of advertiser banners is not a valid answer to the OP's question.  You should make a responsive page and show the right view to the right screen.

Comment: whops I assumed OP was asking about ad banners. If otherwise than I agree with you, responsive is the way to go and there's no standard sizze.